# Android Studio Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: android

главная страница представляет собой Activity Navigation Drawer. Как сделать, чтобы из любой Activity был доступ к Navigation Drawer (Единый для всего проекта)?

Сейчас при переходе к любому Activity, чтобы вернуться в Navigation Drawer нужно использовать кнопку назад и только потом открывать шторку. Хотелось чтобы такая шторка была на всех Activity. Можно ли так сделать? Или придется все Activity делать типа Navigation Drawer?

Comment: Если я верно вас понял, вы хотите одну шторку(одно меню) для своего приложения? Тогда вам достаточно одного активити со шторкой и к нему подключать фрагменты. Если вы всё же хотите несколько активити, то для каждого активити надо будет создать свой Navigation Drawer(они не будутс связаны между собой).

Comment: @Я хочу чтобы из любой части приложения воспользоваться шторкой. Пример Play Marker. Там из любого приложения можно открыть шторку

Comment: Смотрите. Оно так и будет. Используете одно Activity Navigation Drawer.  У вас будет контейнер, куда будете подставлять свои фрагменты. И шторку вы можете вызвать в любое время из любого места(те фрагменты, которые подключены к этому активити). Android Studio предлагает шаблон  Navigation Drawer, изучите его и добавляйте свои фрагменты(активности).

Comment: @вот смотрите при создании активити (MainActivity) создались несколько layout. Судя по кодам разметки, за шторку отвечает layout  activity_main элемент NavigationView (id - nav_view). Я пытаюсь импортировать этот элемент в другое активити <include
        layout="@layout/"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />. Вот что в layout вставлять? ведь там не только nav_view находтся, но и другой элемент

Comment: Я могу вечером скинуть не большой пример. Тебе нужно работать с контейнерами, забудь о создание новых активити. Посмотри как  активити подключает фрагмент, тебе нужно будет создать свои фрагменты и их подключить.

Comment: @ВиталийРобиновский жду примера)

Answer (score 1):

Вернемся к тому что вы создали приложение и выбрали шаблон `Activity Navigation Drawer` в Android Studio.

Для начала нам нужно добавить `Fragment`

```
public class SettingFragment extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

для него `layout` сверстаете сами, может для теста кнопку кинуть.

Перейдем в наше `Activity`

Объявим переменные

```
  private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager myFragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
```

В методе `OnCreate()`. Тут объявим стартовый фрагмент который будет отображаться на активити

```
myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();



if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        // при первом запуске программы
        fragmentTransaction = myFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        // добавляем в контейнер при помощи метода add()
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_main_clan, new FragmentSetting);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Теперь добавим код в `public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

Тут я описал только для двух кнопок бокового меню. Вы конечно делаете под себя и подставляете для себя фрагменты, которые вам нужны.

```
 if (id == R.id.nav_clan) {

               fragmentTransaction = myFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            // меняем в контейнер при помощи метода replace()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main_clan, new FragmentSetting);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_find) {
               fragmentTransaction = myFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            // меняем в контейнер при помощи метода replace()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main_clan, new FragmentSetting);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
```

Код не претендует на супер отличный. Ибо как видите тут есть дублирование кода, ну это вы уже сами можете решить эту проблему сами. И если вам надо передавать данные между фрагментами, в инете много примеров и статей. Рекомендую вам почитать про взаимодействие фрагментов с активити. И к примеру про эту функцию `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);`

Если будут вопросы, пишите. Извини, вчера был очень загруженный день

Comment: Что такое R.id.content_main_clan? id Фрагмента? Layout?

Comment: Что такое new FragmentSetting? Название класса? Но он же наоборот пишется SettingFragment. (У меня подчеркивает красным)

Comment: "Перейдем в наше Activity"? Какое активити? которое NavigationView? или другие, которые создаются по обычному макету?

Comment: "Для начала нам нужно добавить Fragment" А разве мне не нужен фрагмент (шторка), которая находится в NavigationView

Comment: content_main_clan, это у меня. У вас будет  (content_main) - это наш контейнер(та область видимости) которую мы будем заменять контейнером.  
FragmentSetting это произвольное название для моего фрагмента(вы можете по разному назвать, как вам угодно).  
При создание проекта, у вас будет одно активити. Я не знаю как вы его назвали, у меня допустим MainActivity.
Насчет шторки я не понял. Ведь доступ к нему мы получаем в активити, и обрабатываем нажатие в методе 
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)

Comment: Еще раз  повторю, почитайте про взаимодействие фрагментов с активити. Если вы примените этот этот способ, у вас получится то что вы хотели. Только будет одно активити и остальные фрагменты. Вот тут гифка того результата который вы можете  достичь
https://cdn.journaldev.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/android-navigation-drawer.gif

Comment: можете скинуть ваш проект, в качестве образца. Так легче понять

Comment: Можно даже пробный, чисто только с этой функциональной частью

Comment: Сейчас сделаю. Пару минут

Comment: https://ru.files.fm/u/pwaumfdk
Посмотрите

Comment: В свое проекте в MainActivity пытаюсь добавить фрагмент при первом запуске программы. fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_main,new FragmentMy()); Так вот, у меня не видит не layout. Из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: Все понял, это не название layout

Comment: Вот вы создали класс Plus2Fragment и наследуете от Fragment, а как мне работать с элементами, например кнопками, прописывать для них методы и т.д. Ведь должно layout должна наследоваться от AppCompatActivity, чтобы работать с элементами, а множественного наслоедования в Java нету?

Comment: и если вы скинете обновленный проект, то будет просто замечательно

Comment: Нет. Вы просто указывается в методе OnCreate какой layout используете. И просто как в активити подключаете кнопки. Единественное отличие что в OnCreate() будете не напрямую  ID получать кнопки, а через view

Comment: Вот есть метод onCreate и оnCreateView. В каком из них инициализировать элементы, выполнять методы, которые должны выполняться еще до вывода фрагмента на экран. Например метод, подгрузки данных из БД

Comment: Почитайте в чем разница методов.  Я использую паттерн MVP. И у меня презентер(класс)  инициализируется в OnCreateView(). Там проходит обращение к базе данных, и так изменяю данные